# Do I have to use migrations when updating a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, migration

If I want to modify a model class and update the database accordingly, do I have to use a migration?

Comment: Every time you want to modify the database, you'll need to make a migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have to* use migrations, but it is highly recommended to use them when you want to make changes to your database. Migrations make it easier to keep track of database changes over time. Another advantage is that migrations use a Ruby DSL, which means that you don't have to write SQL. The code is database independent, making it easy to switch databases if necessary. It also makes it easy to use different databases in different environments. E.g. SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production.

If you don't care about all this you could just forget about migrations and create, drop and alter tables in your database directly.

Comment: Another advantage: if you are working in teams and one of your developer members changes the schema, you only have to run the new migrations on your local machine and you are up-to-date. Without migrations you will get in troubles..

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

See the [Rails migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for more information.